# what is wrong with this merge sort code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, iterator, mergesort

I am trying to write merge sort using iterators to teach myself c++, but for some reason this code is compiling but the outcome is not sorted. Can someone figure out what is wrong with it? it seems perfectly fine to my untrained eyes.

```
typedef vector<int> vec_int;
typedef vector<int>::iterator vec_int_iter;

void merge_sort(vec_int& vec, vec_int_iter low, vec_int_iter high){
   if(low < high){
      vec_int_iter med = low + (high-low)/2 ;
      merge_sort(vec, low, med);
      merge_sort(vec, med+1, high);
      arrange(vec, low, med, high);
      }
}

void arrange(vec_int& vec, vec_int_iter low, vec_int_iter med, vec_int_iter high){
   vec_int_iter left = low, right = med+1;
   vec_int temp;
   temp.clear();
   vec_int_iter it = temp.begin();

   while(left <= med and right <= high)
      temp.push_back( (*left < *right)? *left++ : *right++ );
   while(left <= med)
      temp.push_back( *left++ );
   while(right <= high)
      temp.push_back( *right++ );

   vec = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong code is `vec = temp`, which will replace the origin vector by a temp vector in some step of merge. Because, every arrange, the temp is only from low to high of the origin vector.
Then the origin vector becomes a sub vector.

You can return a new vector every time, or do it [in place](http://penguin.ewu.edu/class/cscd300/Topic/AdvSorting/MergeSorts/InPlace.html)

Example code, change the arrange function:

```
  void arrange(vec_int& vec, vec_int_iter low, vec_int_iter med, vec_int_iter high){
     vec_int_iter left = low, right = med+1;
     vec_int temp;
     temp.clear();
     while(left <= med and right <= high)
        temp.push_back( (*left < *right)? *left++ : *right++ );
     while(left <= med)
        temp.push_back( *left++ );
     while(right <= high)
        temp.push_back( *right++ );

     vec_int_iter start = low;
     for(vec_int_iter t = temp.begin(); t <temp.end(); t++){
        *start++ = *t;
     }   
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! this makes much more sense!